left derived functor is left (or right?) Kan extension
I am trying to understand relation between left derived functors and left Kan extensions. I tried reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611952 but I got lost. In particular they write that right derived functors correspond to left Kan extensions. I illustrate my confusion on the following example.
Let $A$ be an abelian category with enough projectives and $B$ be cocomplete category and let $F:A\to B$ be a right exact functor. Let $D(A)$ and $D(B)$ be derived categories (maybe in infinity categorical sense) of $A$ and $B$. Let $i:A^{proj}\to D(A)$ be a fully faithful inclusion of a subcategory of projective objects into the heart of $D(A)$. Let $f:A^{proj}\to D(B)$ denote composition $A^{proj}\xrightarrow{F}B\to D(B)$ where the last map is the inclusion into the heart of $D(B)$. Then I would like to say that the left Kan extension of $F$ along $i$ is the left derived functor of $F$.
\begin{array}{cc}
A^{proj} &  \\
\downarrow{i} & \searrow \\
D(A) & \xrightarrow{Lan_f} & D(B)
\end{array}
I would like to say that $Lan_f$ is the left derived functor of $F$. Indeed we have two universal properties:

the one for $Lan_f$: for any $G:D(A)\to D(B)$ we roughly get bijection between transformation $Lan_f\implies G$ and $F\to G\circ i$.

the one for the left derived functor of $F$: for any triangulated functor $G$ (can I think about $G$ as for example an exact functor from $D(A)$ to $D(B)$?), then I also get bijection between natural transformations $F\implies G_0$ and transformations $LF\implies G$ (can I say that roughly $G_0$ is the same as $G\circ i$)


somehow because $LF$ and $Lan_f$ satisfy the same universal properties I would like to say that they are the same.
Does it make any sense?
The particular thing I am struggling with is the proof of part (10) of Theorem 3.2.3. in the note https://blogs.cuit.columbia.edu/jr4460/files/2024/09/SeminarSolidGeometrynotes2-1.pdf . In the 4th line of the proof of (10) it is claimed that a certain left derived functor is a left Kan extension (namely the functor $L\square$).

As the paper says, right derived functors are left Kan extensions, and vice versa left derived functors are right Kan extensions. Why are you trying to relate left derived functors with left Kan extensions?

@ZhenLin thanks for the comment. Context of my question is the proof of part (10) of Theorem 3.2.3. in the note https://blogs.cuit.columbia.edu/jr4460/files/2024/09/SeminarSolidGeometrynotes2-1.pdf . In the 4th line of the proof of (10) it is claimed that a certain left derived functor is a left Kan extension (namely the functor $L\square$). I don't fully understand this proof and I was wondering whether there is a general relation to left derived functors and left Kan extensions.

You are confusing levels. Left Kan extension, as an operation, is a left adjoint. Left adjoints, and left derived functors, are right Kan extensions. There is no contradiction.
